# Why do I get a NameError when using input()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting an error executing this code:

```
nameUser = input("What is your name ? ")    
print (nameUser)
```

The error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DALY/Desktop/premier.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'klj' is not defined
```

What's going on?

Comment: Enter your name as a string eg `'Tom'`. Alternatively, use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: Some versions of python use `input()` as the keyboard input function, and other versions use `raw_input()`.  Try using `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: yes thanx it works with raw_input()  ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using Python 2 for which the [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=raw_input#input) function tries to evaluate the expression entered. Because you enter a string, Python treats it as a name and tries to evaluate it. If there is no variable defined with that name you will get a `NameError` exception.

To fix the problem, in Python 2, you can use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=raw_input#raw_input). This returns the *string* entered by the user and does not attempt to evaluate it.

Note that if you were using Python 3, `input()` behaves the same as `raw_input()` does in Python 2.

Comment: Why is the function is designed in such a way. The purpose of the function is to just accept the input. What is the need of evaluation of what has been input.

Comment: @darth_coder: the purpose of `raw_input()` is to just accept input and return it as a string. `input()` is different; it evaluates the input. That's how these two functions are defined. Since `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` in Python 3, and `input()` removed altogether, it seems that it was not worth the confusion caused by the poorly named (IMHO) `input()` function. What purpose could it have? If you want to execute user input is one obvious application.

Comment: @mhwake fine but I wanted to understand the design semantic behind the `input` function. I am still confused on what exactly it means to evaluate the input.

Comment: @darth_coder: in Python 2 `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`, so that's what it means to "evaluate the input". Read what `eval()` does for more details. As I suggested, one reason for the existence of `input()` is so that you can easily evaluate user input. If that is not a satisfactory explanation then I think that your question reduces to "what is the purpose of `eval()`?" because that is ultimately what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

In Python2, `input` is evaluated, `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`. When you enter klj, Python tries to evaluate that name and raises an error because that name is not defined.

Use `raw_input` to get a string from the user in Python2.

Demo 1: `klj` is not defined:

```
>>> input()
klj
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'klj' is not defined
```

Demo 2: `klj` is defined:

```
>>> klj = 'hi'
>>> input()
klj
'hi'
```

Demo 3: getting a string with `raw_input`:

```
>>> raw_input()
klj
'klj'
```