# Why do I get the python error saying I don't have the keyboard module when I do?

Tags: python

When I try to run a program that has `import keyboard` it gives me this error even though I installed it:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\test file.py", line 1, in 
import keyboard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'*

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you using Python 2? If so this post may be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493899/python-traceback-most-recent-call-last

Comment: The python version where you installed your module should be the same python version you used to run your app. Check with `python -m pip` for the list of installed modules and `python -V` for versions.

Comment: Learn how to create and use virtual environments. Install and run from the same virtual env avoids these problems.

Comment: Your question is lacking a lot of detail, but my money would be on you having multiple Python installations. One of the most ridiculous things about Python (and it's not alone in this) is that a lot of projects handle package management by just installed Python again. Last time I checked my personal laptop, I had over 50 different installations of Python, including the 2 versions I actually installed manually. You need to make sure that the keyboard module is installed for the Python installation you're using to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you simply don't have the module named `keyboard` installed for the version of python that you're running the script with. Try running `python -m pip install keyboard` in a terminal outside of python to install the module, and try running the script again.

*Assuming [this](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) is the module that's being referenced*

Comment: I did but it still says that.

Comment: Sorry, missed that you said you do have it installed. It could be that the `pip` you ran installed the package for a different version of python that's also installed on your computer. Try running `python -m pip install keyboard` to ensure that pip installs the package in the right place. See [here](https://realpython.com/lessons/why-cant-python-find-my-modules/)

Comment: When I did that it gave me this error while trying to install it on command prompt:                                                                                                                             Requirement already satisfied: keyboard in c:\users\diana\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (0.13.5)

Answer (score 0):

You might have both *Python 2* and *Python 3* installed on your OS, which you can easily check by running this from your terminal:

`pip --version`

If the output ends with *Python 2.X* then you probably have two concurrent versions.

This implies that `pip install keyboard` would have installed the package for the respective Python version (2), i.e. you must explicitly point to *pip3* implementation to get the package in the expected location:

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

Comment: That won't work. First I have a windows, and second I have the latest version of python installed.

Answer (score -1):

Pls  check if you installed the module 'keyboard', If done, make sure you call the function.